# Kivy gives me "CRITICAL" message

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy. Kivy gives me this "CRITICAL" message, but everything is running fine. It also says this: `[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: gtk3(['clipboard_xclip', 'clipboard_xsel', 'clipboard_dbusklipper'] ignored)`.
I took out all the INFO messages that Kivy says. Please advise me if I need to put them back in this question.

Here is the message:

```
[CRITICAL] [Cutbuffer   ] Unable to find any valuable Cutbuffer provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
xclip - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xclip'
  File "/home/maheswar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1093, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/maheswar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/clipboard/clipboard_xclip.py", line 17, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(['xclip', '-version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

xsel - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xsel'
  File "/home/maheswar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1093, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/maheswar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/clipboard/clipboard_xsel.py", line 16, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(['xsel'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

Also I am using Linux. Ubuntu 20.04.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it needs one of the programs for clipboard - `xsel`, `xclip`, etc. - which you have to install using `apt`. ie. `apt install xsel`, `apt install xclip`, etc.

Comment: So can I just install them? Or do I have to choose a specific one?

Comment: you can install one of them or all of them - all depends on you. `Kivy` tries to find one of them. If it find `xsel` then Clipboard will try to use `xsel`, if it doesn't find `xsel` but it find `xclip` then Clipboard will try to use `xclip`